# Raspberry Pi SSH suddenly doesn't work

Tags: ssh

I tried to connect to RPi via SSH using PUTTY on Windows10. But it said "Network error: connection timed out".

It worked yesterday. I re-installed the OS onti the RPi, still doesn't work.

Here is what the RPi command line says:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ssh pi@10.255.7.130
The authenticity of host '10.255.7.130 (10.255.7.130)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:pvuAPomAEMekCCNwAAdCui255rILwTu/+KydOrr9AFU.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.255.7.130' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
pi@10.255.7.130's password: 
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7+ #1110 SMP Mon Apr 16 15:18:51 BST 2018 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Jun  8 10:30:17 2018
```

Here is what my windows console says: 
[image]'

I am using this for a motion camera. The camera is fine. If I typed in 10.255.7.130:8081 into the chromium RPi browser. It will show me the live stream.

Definitely not PUTTY software problem. JuiceSSH app on my phone cannot connect either.

Edit. [full result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KsovMOe1jpdu7vWdvY7Ni7X3Y7hzjB93/view?usp=sharing) of ssh -vvv pi@10.255.7.130 -p 22

Edit2. I changed the wlan0, inet in ifconfig.(giving it a static address.)Still doesn't work.

Comment: In general be VERY careful when you see "The authenticity of host..." The new host you connect to could be anywhere on the internet. Accept only if you know the host is on the local subnet or has an expected IP. In this case you're safe because it shows you your Pi USB camera.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics In this case, the OP is actually connecting from the Pi to the Pi on its own address. This notice appears any time you connect to a device you haven't before. In this case it should be expected. It is very rare to SSH to yourself.

Comment: wow. i missed that. I will delete my answer. thank you.

Comment: Might be worth checking Windows PUTTY configuration to see if it is using an old IP if RPi has new IP allocated by DNS.

Comment: I did a scan using Adanced IP scanner. same old IP address for the Rpi

Comment: @Fabian, I put a link to pdf on my Google drive.

Comment: Almost certainly not a Pi problem - by reinstalling OS you changed ssh keys. Most systems see this as a security issue

Answer (score 1):

When you re-install OS on the SD card, the public key for SSH on the SD card changed even though the host name (i.e. pi@10.255.7.130) remain the same, but your computer (SSH client) still have the old SSH public key for the host pi@10.255.7.130 in the caches. What you need to do is to remove the old SSH key for host pi@10.255.7.130 from your PuTTy caches.

For Mac users, this can be done easily editing the known_hosts file using a text editor and delete the key corresponding to the host ip address:

```
sudo nano ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I'm not a Windows users, but a quick search show that you can delete the outdated keys from PuTTy based on [this instruction](https://techglimpse.com/clear-ssh-rsa-keys-putty-cache-regedit/).

Comment: There are a two. A default and the other one. I delete that other one. SSH still doesn't work.

Comment: try to log in using `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` if you are using Raspbian.

Comment: It says "The authenticity of host 'raspberrypi.local (10.255.8.130)' can't be established" then I said yes to continue, It asked me for password. I kept typing raspberry and getting permission denied.

Comment: So the ssh works, but you have wrong password, what password you type in? by default for newly flashed SD card, it should `raspberry`

Comment: I changed the password. It works now.But when I tried ssh using PUTTY it said "Network error: connection timed out". I tried LemonSSH on Android. It's not connecting either.

Comment: Same issue, your Android has the old key for the IP cached. What happen when using 'ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` is a trick that the ssh client will create a new public key cache even though it is same as `pi@10.255.7.130'. Since you can login to the Raspberry Pi now, if you can't clean the public key cache on Android, the alternative solution would be to change the IP address of Raspberry Pi. so that a new ssh connections can be established.

Comment: I give it a different wlan0 inet IP address. Still doesn't work. I saw the change in ifconfig.